# Why does the BETWEEN command for letters differ for numbers in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, between

My question is why when I input the query

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE year BETWEEN 1990 AND 2000;
```

includes the year 2000 however when I input the query:

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE name BETWEEN 'A' and 'J'
```

movies that begin with J are not included. I don't understand the inconsistency with how the between function works when looking at letters versus numbers. I understand that you could use the % to include it but I would like to know why it works this way.

Comment: maybe [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080187/sql-string-comparison-greater-than-and-less-than-operators) help

Comment: Just use `LEFT(name,1) BETWEEN 'A' and 'J'`

Comment: Altering the column in a `WHERE` clause loses the benefits of indexes. Use `name >= 'A' AND name < 'K'`

Comment: Switching to `BETWEEN 'A' and  'J%'` will not work, it's not `LIKE` using a wildcard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, because `J` is not equal to `Jumanji`. The `BETWEEN A AND B` keyword is equivalent to `>= A AND <= B`

Comment: I think you mean `J < Jumanji` Same as `A < AA`

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with SQL.
Everything starts with `J` (e.g. `JAVA`) is alphabetically greater than `J` itself.

Comment: From SQL point of view there are some considerations. Like Collation or Case Sensitive.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Not rellevant to the OP question. You'll get the same results for all collations and cases.

Answer (score 0):

As Stavr mentions, SQL does not infer additional characters other than the literals you used.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 'A Few Good Men' As Movie
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'Back to the Future' As Movie
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'Call of the Wild' As Movie
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'Captain America' As Movie
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'D Movie' As Movie
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'E Movie' As Movie
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'F Movie' As Movie
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'G Movie' As Movie
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'H Movie' As Movie
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'I Movie' As Movie
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'J Movie' As Movie
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'J Movie 2' As Movie
) it 
WHERE Movie BETWEEN 'A' AND 'J%'
```

Comment: Change the last row to `SELECT 'Ja Movie 2' As Movie` and try again.