# Get Error 3464 Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: vba, ms-access

i get Error 3464 Data type mismatch in criteria expression 
but i no able left it 
what is the problem???

```
Dim strsql As String
strsql = "select * from Shift where DFail Between " & txtVal1 & " and " & txtVal2
Me.RecordSource = strsql
```

Comment: What datatype is `DFail` ?

Comment: it is of short text

Comment: if `DFail` is not a numeric field, it's not going to work. String fields cannot be `Between` values. That's a numeric thing.

Comment: oh yes so i want search between two string what is solution?

Comment: can the string be converted to numeric values? otherwise, it makes no sense.

Comment: is not other way to search on string rang?

Comment: not with `Between` - if it's a single character, and you want to convert it to its ASCII value first so that it's numeric... you could try that... but you didnt even show us what your variables are, nor the values you have in the `DFail` field, so all anyone can do is guess without more information.

Comment: ok i wil convert to number type. thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080187/sql-string-comparison-greater-than-and-less-than-operators

Comment: BETWEEN AND can be used with strings such as: `WHERE fieldname BETWEEN "A" and "C"`. Your SQL is missing apostrophe delimiters. However, results can be not what you expect. Edit question to show sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the single-quotes:

```
strsql = "select * from Shift where DFail Between '" & txtVal1 & "' and '" & txtVal2 & "'"
```

Have in mind though, that text is sorted from left to right, like: `1, 12, 2, 20`.