# How does MySQL >= comparisons work when using a string, rather than an integer?

Tags: mysql

I have a database that has a column with a sequence of numbers, and I'm trying to select a range, but the results I am getting are odd.

The column data type is set to VARCHAR, rather than INT since in the future these might contain alphanumeric values, but for now, they are purely numeric.

I tried a statement like `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE number >= '1' AND number <= '458'"`, but I am not getting numbers from 1 to 458, I'm getting a sequence like 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12... etc.

There are numbers missing, so I assume SQL is applying a logic that I am not familiar with. This query does give me the expected results if I do the search with integers, without the single quotes.

Can someone help me understand the logic SQL uses with strings, I was under the impression that SQL converted the values to integers if applicable?

Comment: In lexicographical order, `120` comes before `13`.

Comment: 'If both arguments in a comparison operation are strings, they are compared as strings' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL string comparison, greater than and less than operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080187/sql-string-comparison-greater-than-and-less-than-operators)

Answer (score 0):

When you apply `WHERE number >= '1' AND number <= '458'` to the column which is VARCHAR then **the values are compared as strings**, symbol-by-symbol according to current COLLATION, and the string values like `'1'`, `'2'`, `'11'`, `'458'` matches this condition whereas the values `'5'`, `'78'`, `'4581'`, `'01'` does not match. And you "loose" some values.

If you want to obtain continuous **numbers** list then you must use **numeric** compare. And hence you must convert string-type value of `number` column to numeric datatype. You may do this explicitly (for example, with CAST() function) or implicitly (for example, with `number + 0` expression).